# AndroidStudio 3.0: Java 8 stream not compile (Call requires API level 24)

Tags: android-studio-3.0

Java 8, and I install new Android Studio 3.0.

Add code:

```
 List<String> myList =   Arrays.asList("a1", "a2", "b1", "c2", "c1");

        myList
                .stream()
                .filter(s -> s.startsWith("c"))
                .map(String::toUpperCase)
                .sorted()
                .forEach(System.out::println);
```

But I get compile error:

```
Call requires API level 24 (current min is 15) java.util.stream.Collection
```

Comment: That's expected behavior. A min SDK level of API 15 corresponds to Ice Cream Sandwich, 4.0.3. A 6 year old runtime on a device can't magically support new Java 8 *API* that didn't exist when it was originally created. What you get with AS 3.0 (for minSDK < 24) is support for (a lot of) Java 8 *language* features (e.g. interface default methods), but not for the new Java 8 *API* (on such old devices).

Answer (score 15):

In order to use Streams and other java 8 API without requiring minimum API level 24, you need to do the following:

- Upgrade Android Gradle Plugin to 4.0.0 or higher

  ```
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0
  ```
- Then add this dependency to your build.gradle file:

  ```
  dependencies { 

     coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.0.6'

     ....
  }
  ```
- Finally Add this to your build.gradle file:

  ```
  compileOptions {

      // Flag to enable support for new language APIs
      coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true

      targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
      sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
  ```

Enjoy Java 8 Streams and Time APIs :)

Answer (score 9):

While there is a bunch of Java 1.8 support in Android Studio 3.0 (lambdas, method references, default interface methods), not all of 1.8 is supported for all Android APIs.  In particular, `java.util.stream` is not supported until API 24.

See the developer docs: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html#supported_features

A good library to get backported Java 1.8 libraries such as `java.util.stream` is StreamSupport: https://github.com/streamsupport/streamsupport

Comment: Also not support "try resources". Show message: "Try-with-resources requires API level 19 (current min is 15)".

Comment: Well that is just plain nonsense. Why are they calling it Java 8 if they don't abide by the standard?!